# jQuery Ajax to send URL for rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating a PV counter app with rails, and to achieve that, I want to put a jQuery script in another site's HTML file to pass information about the site's url to my rails app. In the end, I want to save the url in DB once the site is visited.
So far, I am trying to make jQuery script for sending data to rails, and I wrote this. How do I send the target site's url?

```
    <script src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(function(){
     $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      type: "GET",
      data: url of the site
       })
    });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href` or `window.location.origin` which ever suits you and pass it in the data field.
**UPDATED**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
 $(function(){
 //Passing data to rails controller, you can do it like this:
 var webURL = {fullURL: window.location.href,
               domain: window.location.origin
              };//for getting complete url,or window.location.origin for domain alone.
 function recordURL(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/viewcounter/counter',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json'
  data: webURL,
  success: function(data){
                console.log('success '+data);
              },
              error: function(data){
                console.log('error '+data);
              }
   });
   }
   recordURL();
});
</script>
```

In **viewcounter_controller.rb**, please change the function name to **def counter**, as counter is defined in the routes and not **count**.

```
  def counter
    url = params[:fullURL]
    Viewcounter.create(site_url: url)
    render text:'Ok'.to_json
  end
```

And at last remove the jquery migrate script as it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you very much!
For now I need to figure out  how to receive the information on rails and create action or method... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for the adding information.
Now my controller called viewcounter is like this.
` ` 
` def count
    url = params[:fullURL]
    Viewcounter.create(site_url: url)
 end` 

and I also allowed cross domain access as follows.(application.rb)

`config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
}) ` 

Also I created an HTML file written the above jQuery code in it, and opened in a browser. This should, I think, make record in DB, but it didn't. 
Why? I'm sorry for continuous questions.

Comment: I got some errors in browser console:

`GET file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`GET file://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`GET file:///Users/name/Desktop/jquery.xdomainajax.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ practice.html:12`

Seems jQuery is not being called?

I did not get any errors in rails. I just wondered, do I have to make routing like localhost:3000/viewcounter/count ?

Yes, the server is running on local, webrick. Is it going to be a problem? Thank you.

Comment: Ok so, it seems you have created a webpage for testing, the src path in your script tags are not properly mentioned, can you just post the script tags where you are trying to load xdomsinajax, jquery-migrate. You can use CDNs directly, `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.‌​min.js"></script>` and `<script src="correct/path/to/xdomainajax.js"></script>`.

Comment: I put the script tag as follows
`<body>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script> <!-- for cross domain-->
  <script>
 $(function(){
 //Passing data to rails controller, you can do it like this:
 var webURL = {fullUrl: window.location.href
              };//for getting complete url,or window.location.origin for domain alone.
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/viewcounter/count',
  type: 
  data: 
   })
});
</script>
</body>`

Just before </body>.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understood what you wrote. Did you mean I should use

 `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.‌​‌​min.js"></script>`
 
instead of what I wrote?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english and thank you so much again for your big help.
Just to make this easier, I pushed source code to Github. Please use as a reference.
[link](https://github.com/nabemoto/ajaxapp)

I also placed my sample html file where jquery is written in app/views/jquerytag.html.

Comment: Still getting following erros..

`file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`file:///Users/name/Desktop/jquery.xdomainajax.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`practice.html:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Do I need to fix the loading jquery tag, I guess?

Comment: Finally, finally, it worked!! It recorded new column in DB. Except the url is missing.

I am getting 

`file:///Users/name/Desktop/jquery.xdomainajax.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/viewcounter/counter?callback=jQuery111301443258065264…e%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fnabemotoaya%2FDesktop%2Fpractice.html&_=1450745766981' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: Yes, params[:fullURL] correctly dictated in my controller. 
I also tried opening HTML file in Firefox, and no errors relative to js were found. On the other hand I still got the same error in Chrome. Does it have to do with this?

Comment: I changed to json in dataType which I didn't realize until you pointed out, but still not recording. However, browser console error is decreased to just one.

file:///Users/name/Desktop/jquery.xdomainajax.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: I am sorry, please edit this line `render text:'Ok'` in controller to `render text:'Ok'.to_json`, is your js file in desktop? and where is practice.html present?

Comment: No problem at all. I fixed it.

Yes, it's on my desktop, and still not recording...

Comment: Change your src to `<script src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>`, the AJAX function is written in xdomainajax right? Did you try directly keeping the ajax function on page, because it worked for me,

Comment: Yes, my code is just like that.
I tried puting js tag on my blog which is online, and it did record a column, but not url. I'm getting this error in this case.

`http://2uncertain-future.tumblr.com/jquery.xdomainajax.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I googled xdomainajax.js a bit, but I haven't got a clue..

Comment: I am sorry, I omitted 

`domain: window.location.origin
              };//for getting complete url,or window.location.origin for domain alone.`

and I fixed.
And it finally worked!!!!
Thank you so much for your huge huge help!!!!